# Java OutOfMemoryError global hook

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

Is there any global hook I can set for detecting `OutOfMemoryError` ?

I have a massively parallel compute service with lots of memory allocation.
We do our best to tune it's parallelism, so that not too much memory is consumed.
Once every several months, we get an `OutOfMemoryError` in production that load testing did not sniff out.

Once this happens, the server enters an unstable state. All kinds of shared resourcePools (like connectionPools and threadPools) enter an `IllegalState`, and the server starts returning errors on healthy requests.

At this stage, the right thing is to bounce the "sick" machine. We can detect that eventually based on the error rate coming from that machine in the cluster. However: Once we wait for detection: That machine is sending a bunch of false 40X errors to our clients. These requests could have been handled succesfully by other healthy nodes in our cluster.

From my perspective: Once any OutOfMemoryError has occured: We should bounce the machine as quickly as possible. Is there any global hook I can set for detecting `OutOfMemoryError` so that I don't have to write multiple `catch(OutOfMemoryError){Shutdown}` across our code?

Comment: Did you try `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`?

Comment: Maybe you just want to use the `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` option?

Comment: @Holger Add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it